# DFP Ads Tracking in SiteCatalyst (Adobe Analytics)

Tags: adobe, adobe-analytics, google-dfp

***Problem:*** In our site, we are using DFP ads, which are published into our web pages by third party (i.e. google DFP tool).

As per requirement we need to show tracking data for DFP ads (like which ads are clicked, how many times etc) into our omniture site catalyst tool but we are not able to find image id/ iFrame id or anything which is related to this DFP ad campaign.

It seems that we do not have any control over html area in which dfp ad tags are running into our site. On click of ad images, its moving on different domain. Like if current domain is www.MainDomain.com/currentPage then moving onwww.AdDomain/AdItemPage

So, can anyone please suggest us how we can achieve this.
We don't have Adobe Audience Manager tool. We have only Adobe Omniture Analytics to capture DFP ad's data.

***Note:*** As of now we are trying to achieve this by preparing a 're-directive url' ( ***https://webanalyticsfordevelopers.com/2013/10/01/redirect-tracking/*** ), but not sure whether it will work or not.

Comment: Did I get it right that rather than placing DFP's tags directly on your page you use some 3rd party that in turn incorporates DFP's calls?

Comment: If yes you can monitor impressions via DFP's 3rd party impression url and clicks through a 3rd party tracker like you mentioned